# External dll is referencing current project's web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, web-config

I've got two projects, WebAPI project as A and MVC4 project as B.
The dll of A project is referenced in B project.
I found that A's dll is using the config setting in B's web.config.
These projects have different definition for corresponding web.config.

So how can I do A's dll to use its own web.config and not to use B's web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration file is read only from starter project. You can merge configs if they differ in appsettings or connectionstrings. But if they differ in system settings like .net version, authentication and so on, you should launch your projects separately.

You're doing strange things, because MVC4 has initial support for WebApi. You can extract business logic from WebApi into another project. Do you really need to have WebApi controllers in separate project?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to put these two projects in separate server location. For this case,some config cannot be merged because of the security reason.So, WebAPI project need to read it own web.config.